# PyCharm 2016 and lline waprs on copy/pasting

Tags: python, pycharm

can someone tell me if theres some way to disable the autoformating, when copy/pasting?

Every time i paste some line, thats longer than PEP-8-Max line, PyCharm automaticly inserts line warps. Thats realy anoying.

I'm using the professional Version.

Many thanks
rene

Comment: Have a look in settings wrap

Comment: don't seem to find that setting. can you tell me where it can be found?

Answer (score -1):

(On a mac)
 
To get my editor to stop auto wrapping long lines of code I did this.
*PyCharm --> Preferences --> Editor --> Code Style --> Default Options --> Right margin (columns): 999*

The editor wouldn't let me set a value larger than 999.
It's not perfect but it reduced the annoyance factor quite a bit for me.

Hope it helps.